# Why does Cisco WebEx only work by running a temporary application?

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, webex

When starting or joining a Cisco WebEx meeting using Chrome on Windows 10, it always requires the use of the provided temporary application. Why does the add-on not work or what is required to get it to work?

### Step 1 - Cisco WebEx Extension

The [Cisco Webex Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cisco-webex-extension/jlhmfgmfgeifomenelglieieghnjghma) appears to be installed. Installing the extension is Step 1 of 2.

*The site prompts for the installation of the extension*
[image: Add WebEx to Chrome]

---

*Chrome prompts to install the extension*
[image: Add extension]

---

*The extension shows up as installed*
[image: Installed extension]

---

### Step 2 - Install the Cisco WebEx add-on

Step 2 is shown and after downloading the executable and running it, nothing appears to happen. The only way to start or join a meeting is to use the provided temporary application.
[image: Step 2 of 2: Install the Cisco WebEx add-on]

### Using a temporary application

[Joining a Meeting Using 'Run a temporary application'](https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/WBX000026711) describes the only process which works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [Cisco Collaboration Help](https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/n8omowv) article last updated on Jun 11, 2018:

> Announcing the retirement of the Webex App for Chrome

It also lists limitations for using the Chrome extension:

> - Limited to attendees only. Hosts must use the Webex Web App or the desktop app.
> - Attendees can only join Cisco Webex Meetings on sites running WBS30 or higher.
> - Does not support the Cisco Webex Meetings product meetings.webex.com.
> - Attendees cannot join meetings with end-to-end encryption enabled.
> - Attendees cannot join meetings on the "VoIP-only" site type.
> - Does not support content sharing

So it's likely that it just doesn't work anymore. The [article referenced](https://collaborationhelp.cisco.com/article/en-us/n1pxgbz) in the announcement suggests that you now can use a HTML5 based solution that doesn't require any extensions anymore.